# RemoteApp RDS Server 2016 - Menus Opening to left

Tags: terminal-server, rds, remoteapp, display

I have setup a new RDS server in Azure running server 2016. I have deployed some programs through remoteapp but am not having a problem with the menus on all remoteapp programs.

The menus slide out to the left instead of to the right. This happens with Microsoft's own programs also, as can been seen here:

[image]

If I run the app directly on the server it is fine. If I run on the server through the remoteapp the problem persists.

I'm sure it's a simple fix but I am new to remoteapp and need pointed in the general direction of a fix. I have tried looking at display settings but didn't see anything in there.

Comment: Still haven't found any solution for this.  Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Anyone have a workaround for this?